# Making use of SQL Alias (as) in PHP

Tags: php, sql, session, alias

I'm using the following query to pull records from a database:

```
$query = "SELECT password, salt, 'jobseeker' as type
FROM ip_jobseekers
WHERE ipJ_username = '$username'
UNION
SELECT password, salt, 'company' as type
FROM ip_companies
WHERE ipC_username = '$username';";

$result = mysql_query($query);

//No Such User
if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    header('Location: login.php?login=fail'); exit;}
```

to create a new session:

```
//login successful
else {$_SESSION['user'] = $username;}
```

I want to include the type of user in the session so that I can specify what content is displated to the user. Is it possible to make use of the "'company' as type" and "'jobseeker' as type" parts of that query to do this? I've make a few attempts at doing it but I've had no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Kai.

Comment: DON"T USE THE MYSQL_ FUNCTIONS!

Comment: Can I ask why? I've just figured out how to do it but should I not use it? I'm afraid I don't know much about this.

Comment: The mysql_ set of functions don't actually tell if there's an error, they just silently die.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya you can ask them using `mysql_error()` function.

Comment: Kai, what exactly did you try with your attempts? there should be no problem in using these fields. If you want us to find an typo in your code, you have to provide that code. Not so much though. You know, only relevant one

Comment: Hi, I've sorted this out now, although I'm not sure how valid it is looking at the other comments... but it works; `$qData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

else {$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
$_SESSION['permission'] = $qData['type'];}`

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely **no difference** between "regular" and aliased fields. You can use the latter as well as any other.

Answer (score 0):

to find any error in your query you can run the query like below

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
```

for testing you can use above and you ca redirect to custom error page in production environment.

My personal suggestion is to use PDO. make use of Object oriented Programs to run your code faster and to have standard structure.

Comment: adding `cannot run` words makes no sense as the error message is pretty sel-fexplanatory itself. It could tell you `there is an error in your query`, so, no need to explain anything else. while it is always handy to add the query itself. And, of course, die() should never be used, use trigger_error() instead. it will tell you the place where error occurred and follow server-wide error reporting rules

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you're using the `mysql_` set of functions, which are highly dangerous, and you should move over all your code from ASAP.

Next, you should NOT be stringing up queries like this, because your application will grow into this behemoth of SQL everywhere (in the HTML, in the Views, EVERYWHERE), you should probably be using some kind of class/object system where you wrap around the SQL.

And, you should know about the SQL [AND](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) clause (I feel horrible linking w3schools, but, that's all I can find right now).

Comment: what's so highly dangerous in mysql_ set of functions? Could you provide an example to prove your words?

Comment: They don't actually tell you about errors, they just silently die.

Comment: mysqli does the same. is it "extremely dangerous" too?

Comment: there are no "extremely dangerous" words on that page. have you got a certain example of whatever extremely dangerous vulnerability in mysql_ functions?

Comment: They silently die. That's pretty dangerous.

Comment: mysqli does the same. is it "extremely dangerous" too?